# Minimize App Produces Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState

Tags: android, onsaveinstancestate

I'm making an async request with retrofit, on the middle of request i minimize the app and crash the app...

My log error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.checkStateLoss(FragmentManager.java:1842)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.enqueueAction(FragmentManager.java:1860)
at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commitInternal(BackStackRecord.java:650)
at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commit(BackStackRecord.java:609)
at br.com.ole.oleconsignado.util.ActivityUtils.replaceFragmentToActivityWithBackStack(ActivityUtils.java:109)
at br.com.ole.oleconsignado.ui.fragment.init.LoginFragment.notifyGetProspectSuccess(LoginFragment.java:410)
at br.com.ole.oleconsignado.ui.presenter.LoginPresenter$4.onSuccess(LoginPresenter.java:91)
at br.com.ole.oleconsignado.ui.presenter.LoginPresenter$4.onSuccess(LoginPresenter.java:88)
at br.com.ole.oleconsignado.network.RestCallback.onResponse(RestCallback.java:24)
at retrofit2.ExecutorCallAdapterFactory$ExecutorCallbackCall$1$1.run(ExecutorCallAdapterFactory.java:68)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6165)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:888)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:778)
```

Here it's the method I call if the request return success:

```
ActivityUtils.replaceFragmentToActivityWithBackStack(getFragmentManager(), IncompleteStatusFragment.newInstance(mLogin.getCustomerId(), mCustomer, prospect, mLogin), R.id.container_login);
```

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

That is obvious, if you minimize the app then you won't be able to replace the fragment as your app is not in focus & throw `java.lang.IllegalStateException`. you should probable maintain a flag & in onResume of your activity if that flag is true then replace the fragment.

like

```
@Override
public void onPause() {
   mIsActivityVisible = false;
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
   mIsActivityVisible = true;
   if(mShouldReplaceFragmentOnResume) {
      mShouldReplaceFragmentOnResume = false;
      // replace fragment
   }
}

// On Success response
onSuccessOfYourCall() {
   if(mIsActivityVisible) {
       //replace fragment
   } else {
       mShouldReplaceFragmentOnResume = true;
   }
}
```